# How would I get individual data from my angular observable in the html part of my component if my observable is an array?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

The html part we care about is
`<p> {{service.myObs$ | async}} </p>`

When doing this, it shows all of the variables in the array Observable. I want to access different variables from it individually. This observable is a Observable that is a string[]. I want to access an individual string at a time from it. My first thought was to do:
`{{service.myObs$[1] | async}}`

This didn't work. It compiled, but didn't show anything. My second thought was to do:
`{{service.myObs$ | async[1]}}`

This doesn't even compile because you obviously aren't supposed to put a [] after async it isn't the array.

Does anyone know how I would manage to access only one of the variables in myObs$ instead of all of them?

Comment: Could you try `{{ (service.myObs$ | async)[1] }}` ?

Comment: @eko that worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I just wasted way too much time trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. I'll provide it as an answer then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this syntax:

```html
 {{ (service.myObs$ | async)[1] }}
```